# TYPO3 10.4 - How add in hreflang, more Output, only 2 BE Language?

Tags: yaml, typo3, seo, typoscript, typo3-10.x

my Request in TYPO3 10.4 with the tx_seo is for only two Lang: de-CH and en-US like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-CH" href="https://www.example.org/produkte/test-schiene"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://www.example.org/produkte/test-schiene"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-AT" href="https://www.example.org/produkte/test-schiene"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://www.example.org/en/products/test-rail"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.org/en/products/test-rail"/>
```

I have in the Backend only the 2 Language: de-CH = 0 / en-US = 1
My first thought was, the site config.yaml like this (de-DE or de-AT take the lang-id: 0 from de-CH):

```
languages:
  -
    title: 'Deutsch (CH)'
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_CH.utf8
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: 'test'
    navigationTitle: DE
    hreflang: de-CH
    direction: ''
    flag: ch
    languageId: 0
  -
    title: 'Deutsch (DE)'
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.utf8
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: 'test'
    navigationTitle: DE
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: 0
  -
    title: Englisch
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.utf8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: 'test'
    navigationTitle: EN
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ''
    flag: en-us-gb
    languageId: 1
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
```

But it dont work, the HTML Output is this:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://www.example.org/produkte/test-schiene"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://www.example.org/en/products/test-rail"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.org/produkte/test-schiene"/>
```

There overright the de-CH Language with the de-DE config.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

A different translation should have a unique language id! It looks like you would like to use a "generic" German language and not a country specific variant. But if you just have one generic German version you should decide if you are talking swiss German or german German. And use it accordingly.

If your texts are in swiss German its bad to claim they are German German

Comment: mhh, yes but DE-AT, DE-CH is the same language like DE-DE :) But there are 3 Countrys

Comment: Why then not using just "de"?

Comment: The SEO advice says: DE-DE, DE-AT, DE-CH should be the same as a link. They are three countries, but with the same languages.

Maybe I have to create it statically with tyoscript?

Answer (score 0):

The "default" hreflang from the Ext: tx_seo / site-config take the BE Language.
And the other hreflang (DE-DE, DE-AT), i creating this with typoscript.

```
page.headerData {
    900 = COA
    900 {
        10 = TEXT
        10 {
            typolink {
                parameter.data = page:uid
                additionalParams = &L=0
                useCacheHash = 1
                # add all get parameters from the current URL
                addQueryString = 1
                returnLast = url
                forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
            }

            wrap = <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="|" />

            append = TEXT
            append.char = 10
        }
        
        20 = TEXT
        20 {
            typolink {
                parameter.data = page:uid
                additionalParams = &L=0
                useCacheHash = 1
                # add all get parameters from the current URL
                addQueryString = 1
                returnLast = url
                forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
            }

            wrap = <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-AT" href="|" />

            append = TEXT
            append.char = 10
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know if this is the best way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Google says the following about [Supported language/region codes in hreflang](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions?hl=en#language-codes)

> Supported language/region codes The value of the hreflang attribute
> identifies the language (in ISO 639-1 format) and optionally a region
> (in ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format) of an alternate URL. If there's only
> one code specified, Google assumes the code to be a language code. The
> language doesn't need to be related to the region. For example:
>
> - de: German language content, independent of region
> - en-GB: English language content, for GB users
> - de-ES: German language content, for users in Spain
>
> **Warning:** Don't specify a country code by itself. Google
> doesn't automatically derive the language from the country code. To
> simplify your labeling, you can specify a language code by itself. For
> example:
>
> - be: Belarusian language, independent of region (Google
>   doesn't understand this to be Belgium)
>
> To restrict the page to a
> specific region, specify the country code after the language. For
> example:
>
> - nl-be: Dutch for users in Belgium
> - fr-be: French for users in Belgium

So if you have only one German page, which is identical for all German-speaking users (and that's how I understand your request), then it is sufficient to specify "de" as hreflang. There is no need to specify a region additionally.

---

If you still want to change the output of the HrefLang links, [TYPO3 offers since version 10.3 the ModifyHrefLangTagsEvent event](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Events/Events/Frontend/ModifyHrefLangTagsEvent.html) with which exactly that is possible.

In your case it could look like this (assuming your HrefLang that TYPO3 generates is for de-CH):

In `EXT:my_extension/Configuration/Services.yaml`

```
services:
    Vendor\MyExtension\HrefLang\EventListener\OwnHrefLang:
        tags:
          - name: event.listener
            identifier: 'my-ext/ownHrefLang'
            after: 'typo3-seo/hreflangGenerator'
            event: TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Event\ModifyHrefLangTagsEvent
```

and in `EXT:my_extension/Classes/HrefLang/EventListener/OwnHrefLang.php`

```
namespace Vendor\MyExtension\HrefLang\EventListener;

use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Event\ModifyHrefLangTagsEvent;

class OwnHrefLang
{
   public function __invoke(ModifyHrefLangTagsEvent $event): void
   {
      $hrefLangs = $event->getHrefLangs();
      $request = $event->getRequest();

      $deHrefLang = $hrefLangs['de-CH'];
      $event->addHrefLang('de-DE', $deHrefLang);
      $event->addHrefLang('de-AT', $deHrefLang);
    }
}
```

---

I hope the answer is helpful for you. :)